# Angular material datatable doesn't render when subscription data update

Tags: angular

I have data table inside of `ng-template` and I'm using it several places in the component. There are several data sources and different data tables so I'm displaying datatable using ng container, with different binded data.

I'm using below datatable without ng-container and ng-template structure in different components and its works pretty well. But when I used like this, table doesn't fill when given data is updated.

ng-container

```js
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="datatableTemplate"
              [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{posts: confirmedCases, postCount: confirmedCasesTotal, loading: confirmedCasesLoadingState}">
</ng-container>
```

and datatable template

```js
<ng-template let-posts let-postCount let-loading #datatableTemplate>
  <div class="table-container">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="posts">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="user">
        <th mat-header-cell [width]="150" *matHeaderCellDef> User</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <a [routerLink]="'/users/' + element.user_id">{{ element.user | shorten }}</a>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container [matColumnDef]="def.column" *ngFor="let def of tableHeaders">
        <th mat-header-cell [width]="def.width" *matHeaderCellDef> {{ def.title }} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <span [class.text-danger]="def.column === 'status_title' && element[def.column] === 'Banned'"
              [class.text-warning]="def.column === 'status_title' && element[def.column] === 'Suspended'"
              [title]="element[def.column]">
          <fa-icon class="datatable-icon" *ngIf="def.hasOwnProperty('icon')" [icon]="def.icon"></fa-icon>
          {{ element[def.column] | shorten: 30}}
        </span>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnDefinitions; sticky: true"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnDefinitions;"></tr>
    </table>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3" *ngIf="loading">
      <div class="spinner-border text-secondary" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <mat-paginator [length]="postCount" (page)="onPageChange($event)"
                   [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
    </mat-paginator>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: one question - data itself is not updating or it is not updation on view only ?

Comment: @piyushjain, only viet not updating. when I log the data I'm able see changes. Also if I use specific component property in template as datasource, its render the datatable. But if pass data as template context nothing happened.

Comment: I faced same issue. Then came up with this solution.
add this `@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;`
then whereever you are getting updated data use this `this.table.renderRows();`.

Comment: also you can check table's all data using `this.table`

Comment: @piyushjain I can't get table component. it shows undefined. I also tried with turning static true but nothing happened

Comment: did you import this ? `import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';`

Comment: @piyushjain yeah of course

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz demo link ? It will easier to understand and fix actual issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211728/discussion-between-piyush-jain-and-teoman-tingir).